# Azure signalr set server timeout

Tags: .net, azure, websocket, signalr

I want to set server timeout on my azure hosted signalr. Im writing web api project in .net core and i've setup this signalr configuration in startup.cs (configureservices and configure respectively):

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        ...
        services.AddSignalR().AddAzureSignalR(Configuration.GetSection("Values")["AzureSignalRConnectionString"]);
        ...
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        ...
        app.UseAzureSignalR(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapHub<GeolocationHub>("/geolocation");
            routes.MapHub<MallHub>("/mall");
        });
        ...
    }
```

Keep alive ping is doing well. Server sends it with 15 seconds interval.
However if I select offline mode in chrome devtools and come back online after e.g. 40 seconds, server still responds with keep alive ping: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ptv6Y.png.

I don't want this behavior. I want server to treat connection lost when client doesn't respond for a given interval (30 seconds in my example).

I've also seen that page refreshing keeps previous connection alive and creates a new one. OnDisconnectedAsync() in my hub isn't called when I'm doing F5. In the end I got 429 from azure signalr service - on azure portal there is a diagram showing 20 concurrent connections (I've chosen free tier with 20 simultaneously connections available).

Will OnDisconnectedAsync() be called when client doesn't respond at a given interval? I've got a state in my hub that keeps track of connected users. I'd like to update this collection whenever user is connected/disconnected.

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Seller, User")]
    public class MallHub : Hub
    {
        private readonly IOfferService _offerService;

        public MallHub(IOfferService offerService)
        {
            _offerService = offerService;
        }

        public static Dictionary<string, UserInMall> ConnectedUsers { get; set; }

        public override async Task OnConnectedAsync()
        {
            try
            {
                var userId = Context.User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "id").Value;
                var mallCodename = Context.User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "mcn").Value;
                ConnectedUsers.Add(userId, new UserInMall() { ConnectionId = Context.ConnectionId, MallCodename = mallCodename });
                var offers = await _offerService.GetUserOffersById(userId);
                await Clients.Client(Context.ConnectionId).SendAsync("updateOffers", offers);
                await base.OnConnectedAsync();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw new HubException(e.Message);
            }
        }

        public override Task OnDisconnectedAsync(Exception exception)
        {
            var userId = Context.User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "id").Value;
            ConnectedUsers.Remove(userId);
            return base.OnDisconnectedAsync(exception);
        }

        public async Task SendOfferToUserById(string id, IEnumerable<Contracts.POCO.Offer> offers)
        {
            var userId = Context.User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "id").Value;
            await Clients.Client(ConnectedUsers[userId].ConnectionId).SendAsync("updateOffers", offers);
        }
    }

public class UserInMall
{
    public string ConnectionId { get; set; }
    public string MallCodename { get; set; }
}
```

Is there a better way to maintain hub state? I need this in order to call specific clients from outside the hub. I'm mapping my domain userId to hub connectionId.